# Problems with SQL string with a vowel mutation

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-like, htmlspecialchars

I do execute a SQL string via PHP.

```
SELECT *
FROM dDokumente
WHERE dMandant = '26'
AND dName LIKE '%wäsche%'
AND dActive = '1'
ORDER BY dDokID
```

if I execute it via PHP MyAdmin I get 2 results (which is correct) but as soon as I execute it via my PHP page it shows 0 results.

MySql Database is UTF8_general_ci.

The SQL string seems to be correct if I display it on the page.

Does anyone have an idea what I could do?

Comment: Is your PHP set to be working with UTF-8 too?

Comment: are you devving in windows by any chance?

Comment: Server is a centos and my development OS is OSX,...

Comment: Have you configured your MySQL connection to use a UTF8 based collation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) (I'm guessing you forgot to set the charset on the connector)

Comment: It was the charset on the connector,... that you all for your help! would you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure everything is UTF-8.

Open your PHP script in your IDE, and check the file encoding is also set to UTF-8.

In windows, you'll probably be on windows-1252 or iso-8559-1 (AVOID!)

Also, if it's on a web page, make sure your HTML also declares the file encoding as utf-8 in the meta tags

Comment: I just revised everything,...
Document is utf-8
Meta Tags are uff-8.
But still nothing,...